# how to print a single output in for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

How can I print only one output in for loop? If the number is in array then it will print `"Present"` but if the number is not in the array it will print `"Nope"`. And I need to search the number the user inputed.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int numOfLoop = in.nextInt(); // How many loop I want.
int[] num = new int[numOfLoop];// Array of the numbers.

for (int i = 0; i < numOfLoop; i++)// getting the numbers.
{

    num[i] = in.nextInt();

}

int searchNum = in.nextInt();// The number that is to be search.

for (int i = 0; i < numOfLoop; i++)// For loop to search the number in the array.
{

    if (num[i] == searchNum) {
        System.out.println("Present");
    }
    if (searchNum != num[i]) {
        System.out.println("Nope");
    }

}
```

**Input**:

```
5 //How many iteration I want
3 21 2 5 23 //Input 5 Number
2 //Number to be searched
```

**output**:

```
Nope
Nope
Present
Nope
Nope
```

**Expected Output:** `Present`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a variable outside the loop and print outside the loop using that variable as below:

```
boolean isMatched = false;

for(int i = 0; i <numOfLoop; i++)//For loop to search the number in the array.
  {

   if(num[i] == searchNum) {
    isMatched = true;
    break;
   }
  }

if(isMatched) {
   System.out.println("Present");
} else {
   System.out.println("Nope");
}
```

**Added Java 8 Solution:**

If you are using Java 8 or above you can use Stream also to replace above for loop. As below :

```
final boolean isMatched = Arrays.stream(num).anyMatch(a -> a == searchNum);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track. All you need is to add else to your conditional statement

```
if(num[i] == searchNum) {
    System.out.println("Present");
   }
   else {
    System.out.println("Nope");
   }
```